# Apache Mesos Install | Missing Libz

Tags: 16.04

I followed all of the indicated [steps](http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/) to install Apache Mesos, but after running the $ ../configure command, i get an error saying that 'libz' is a requirement.  I've tried to google 'libz' but i'm not getting a clear solution.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, Apache Mesos hasn't published releases for 16.04 yet, so I wouldn't expect the one that you downloaded to work.

Comment: @edwinksl i see, that could definitely be a factor. So roll back to 14.04?

Comment: Hmm, maybe there may be ways to do this. Can you try `sudo apt install zlib1g-dev` and compile Apache Mesos again?

Comment: @edwinksl thank you, i'll give that a try tonight.  Can't right now. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: @edwinksl hey buddy, your solution worked. Please post as an answer so i can accept and upvote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution is courtesy of [edwinksl](https://askubuntu.com/users/15003/edwinksl)

```
sudo apt install zlib1g-dev
```